# How do I insert values from two columns into an array for later use with autocomplete?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm doing a program in C# (windows forms) and SQL-Server where I need to take the strings from two columns and put them into an array. I will use that array later in order to implement autocomplete to some textBoxes. The rules are:

- The array should be able to hold whatever the amount of strings I
  have in the columns, this amount may exceed 500 strings and is variable.
- I will need the distinct values from the columns, no duplicates.

I think I'm supposed to use "UNION" for putting together all the strings from the two columns and SqlDataReader with a "while" cycle when putting the strings into the array.

Here is an example table, use it to explain it to me:

```
----------------------------
|    name    |   surname   |
----------------------------
|    John    |   Jackson   |
----------------------------
|   Michael  |    Jones    |
----------------------------
|   Amanda   |    Lopez    |
----------------------------
|  Christina |    Lopez    |
----------------------------
```

So how would the query look like and how would can I put the results into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a concatenate use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name + surname FROM MyTable
```

If you dont want a concatenate you can do this:

```
   SELECT Col1 FROM MyTable
    UNION
    SELECT Col2 FROM MyTable
```

A union will work as long as `Col1` and `Col2` have the same datatype.  Once you have the data you can bring it back to the client side (via a sproc) into a dataset, datatable, or sqldatareader.

The rest should be simple, take the data and store it in an array of some sort.
Either through some sort of loop

```
reader = GetData();
while(reader.read())
 {
  //store into an array...
 }
```

Copy paste this in sql server management studio

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
 col1 varchar(10),
 col2 varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #Test(col1, col2) VALUES('jon', 'jane')
INSERT INTO #Test(col1, col2) VALUES('jane', 'jane')
INSERT INTO #Test(col1, col2) VALUES('bob', 'phil')
INSERT INTO #Test(col1, col2) VALUES('marc', 'phil')
INSERT INTO #Test(col1, col2) VALUES('jon', 'jon')
INSERT INTO #Test(col1, col2) VALUES('jon', 'Jon')
INSERT INTO #Test(col1, col2) VALUES('jane1', 'jane')
INSERT INTO #Test(col1, col2) VALUES('bob2', 'phil')
INSERT INTO #Test(col1, col2) VALUES('marc2', 'phil')
INSERT INTO #Test(col1, col2) VALUES('ste', 'jane')
```

SELECT col1 FROM #test
    UNION
   SELECT col2 FROM #test

```
DROP TABLE #Test
```

The result is:

```
bob
bob2
jane
jane1
jon
marc
marc2
phil
ste
```

Comment: The query will take distinct values from Col1 and distinct values from Col2 but what if there are values in Col1 that are the same as values in Col2?

Also, would be great if you could finish what's inside the "while" cycle :)

Comment: @Alternatex - You're asking for too much help - put some effort into it otherwise it's not really work is it?  Ill help with the Col1 and Col2...all you have to do is compare the 2...`SELECT DISTINCT Col1 FROM MyTable WHERE Col1 NOT IN (SELECT Col2 FROM MyTable)UNION SELECT DISTINCT Col2 FROM MyTable WHERE Col2 NOT IN (SELECT Col1 FROM MyTable)`

Comment: +1 - FYI, you don't need both the `DISTINCT` and the `UNION` - `UNION` will remove dupes from within the individual result sets as well.  It basically applies a `DISTINCT` to the final result set.  `EXCEPT` and `INTERSECT` do the same thing.

Comment: @JNK is right playing too much with UNION and UNION ALL been a long time.